# write the newline between Items which user selected from a openfiledialog using TinyXML in C++

Tags: c++, newline, filenames, openfiledialog, tinyxml

I am using TinyXML library in my project to produce a Xml file. (C++ Visual Studio 2010)

when the user press the Browse Button He/She can select more than one pictures or files.

I want to write each name in one line but all of them between a couple tags. I mean I want this code in output :

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <opencv_storage>
    <images>
    ./images/cam01.jpg
    ./images/cam02.jpg
    ./images/cam03.jpg
    ./images/cam04.jpg
    ./images/cam05.jpg
    ./images/cam06.jpg
    ./images/cam07.jpg
    ./images/cam08.jpg
    ./images/cam09.jpg
    ./images/cam10.jpg
    ./images/cam11.jpg
    ./images/cam12.jpg
    ./images/cam13.jpg
    ./images/cam14.jpg
    </images>
    </opencv_storage>
```

but I dont know How can I write the new line between them . 
by my code here:

```
int NumberOfFile = 0;
  array<String^>^ NamesOfSelectedFiles = gcnew array<String^>(100);

  TiXmlDocument document; 
  TiXmlElement* msg;
  TiXmlDeclaration* dec1 = new TiXmlDeclaration("1.0","","");
  document.LinkEndChild(dec1);

  TiXmlElement * root = new TiXmlElement( "opencv_storage" );  
  document.LinkEndChild( root ); 
  msg = new TiXmlElement("images");

  openFileDialog1->Title = "Select an Image file";

 if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)

  {
     for each (String^ file in openFileDialog1->SafeFileNames)
         {
            String ^orig1 = gcnew String(openFileDialog1->FileName);
             pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch1 = PtrToStringChars(orig1);
             size_t origsize1 = wcslen(wch1) + 1;
             const size_t newsize1 = 100;
             size_t convertedChars1 = 0;
             char nstring1[newsize1];
         wcstombs_s(&convertedChars1, nstring1, origsize1, wch1, _TRUNCATE);

         TiXmlText* txt = new TiXmlText(nstring1);
         msg->LinkEndChild(txt);
         }
              root->LinkEndChild(msg);


          document.SaveFile("VID5.xml");

     }
```

by this Code I produce such file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <opencv_storage>
    <images>C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpgC:\Users\Public  \Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg
    </images>
    </opencv_storage>
```

How Can I write a newline character between this names ?

thank you so much!

Comment: no it does not work ;)

Answer (score 1):

A better/neater solution would be to store each item in its own XML element, e.g.:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <opencv_storage>
    <images>
     <image>./images/cam01.jpg</image>
     <image>./images/cam02.jpg</image>
     <image>./images/cam03.jpg</image>
    </images>
    </opencv_storage>
```

Then you simply have to enum the "image" tags to build up your full list without having to worry about parsing each separate line.

Comment: you mean I add each of them as an Item? no I cant, because my project produce the input for the other project, I should write as the code I wrote. I cant change it:-)